# How to remove a given particular symbol from a string using C#

Tags: xml, string, c#-4.0

I have a string like

```
string value = "Power:'{Comma}'";
```

I need to remove { and } symbols from the string.

I tried value.Replace('{', ' '); and value.Replace('}', ' '); But this gives space. I dont want space, just want to remove the symbol.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the overload that takes strings instead of characters, then you can replace with the empty string:

```
value = value.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
value = value.Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);
```